# Need putty in centos7 to convert ppk file to pem file to transfer files to amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, putty, centos7

Have a ppk key to login into amazon machine. But to login from linux machine it has to be converted into pem file as i read in the following links.

http://sarathlal.com/convert-ppk-file-to-pem-file-connect-to-remote-server-via-ssh-linux/

http://webkul.com/blog/convert-a-ppk-file-to-a-pem-file/

But unable to find / install putty in centos7.

```
[dkanagaraj@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install puttygen
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosv.centos.org
 * extras: centosk3.centos.org
 * updates: centosv.centos.org
No package puttygen available.
Error: Nothing to do

[dkanagaraj@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install putty
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosv.centos.org
 * extras: centosk3.centos.org
 * updates: centosv.centos.org
No package putty available.
Error: Nothing to do

[dkanagaraj@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install putty-tools
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosv.centos.org
 * extras: centosk3.centos.org
 * updates: centosv.centos.org
No package putty-tools available.
Error: Nothing to do

[dkanagaraj@localhost ~]$ sudo yum whatprovides putty
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosv.centos.org
 * extras: centosk3.centos.org
 * updates: centosv.centos.org
No matches found

[dkanagaraj@localhost ~]$ sudo yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosv.centos.org
 * epel: mirror.pregi.net
 * extras: centosk3.centos.org
 * updates: centosv.centos.org
repo id                                                                              repo name                                                                                                           status
base/7/x86_64                                                                        CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                      9,007
epel/x86_64                                                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                      10,122
extras/7/x86_64                                                                      CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                      310
updates/7/x86_64                                                                     CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                   1,687
repolist: 21,126
```

Really appreciated if any other method is available.

Comment: You may need to update your repo.. Try taking a look at this: http://www.tecmint.com/how-to-enable-epel-repository-for-rhel-centos-6-5/

Comment: Centos does supply putty package try this wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/ ... f.i386.rpm
rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install putty

Comment: I installed epel-release repo and tried. but it didnt. Edited my question with repolist available in my machine.

Comment: Is this one time you want the conversion? If yes convert the file on a ubuntu machine if you have one and copy that key to Centos machine

Comment: Thank you @error2007s. I am able to do as you said. Given my answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install putty
puttygen SISPKey.ppk -O private-openssh -o pemkey.pem
cd .ssh
cp pemkey.pem ~/.ssh/
chmod 400 .ssh/pemkey.pem
```

Comment: The only answer which says that there is a _puttygen_ command. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The enlisted steps worked on my CentOS 7 system:

[Download and install EPEL Repository]

```
sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
```

[Install putty]

```
sudo yum install putty
```

Answer (score 1):

***rpmforge*** doesn't seem to be available currently. The enlisted steps worked on my CentOS 7 system:

1. **Download and install EPEL Repository:**
   sudo wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
   sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm
2. **Install putty:** sudo yum install putty

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Amazon Linux 2 you can install EPEL from amazon-linux-extras

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y`

Then simply use

`sudo yum install putty`